# Data filteration based on regular monthly basis

Tags: oracle, hadoop, filter, hive

I want to filter the data according to my requirement in Hive or oracle

```
person month number_of_visits
a 1 12
a 2 10
a 3 20
a 4 10
b 1 12
b 3 15
b 4 12
c 1 10
c 3 18
d 1 14
d 2 18
d 3 26
d 4 34
d 5 36
```

My output requirement is: 
I want to filter persons who visit the mall regularly on month basis.
If I consider persons for 4 months I need only **a** and **d**
because I can see their data for 1,2,3,4 months.

I am unable to meet this requirement.
Can anybody who is good in querying help me?

Comment: Data is like below in tabular format of three columns.
the data is shown as single line not sure why?
three fields are there for each row
person month number_of_visits 
a 1 12\n
a 2 10\n
a 3 20\n
a 4 10\n
b 1 12\n
b 3 15\n
b 4 12\n
c 1 10\n
c 3 18\n
d 1 14\n
d 2 18\n
d 3 26\n
d 4 34\n
d 5 36\n

Comment: Can anyone help me please, i am stuck with this from 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

To select persons who had more than 4 months with visits:

```
select person 
from table
group by person
having count(distinct month) >=4
```

To count consecutive visits its harder. Let's find persons who have at least 4 consecutive visits but only consecutive visits(which is easier than your problem).

```
select person 
from table
group by person
having count(distinct month) >=4
and min(month) = 1  
and max(month) - min(month) = count(distinct month) - 1
```

If you specify starting month and ending month you can use the above queries to resolve your problem.

Comment: The above query is not according to my requirement. I want only below output.
a 1 12
a 2 10
a 3 20
d 1 14
d 2 18
d 3 26

Clearly saying i want records who has regular visit to the mall.
1st month, 2nd month, 3rd Month is the regular visit.
1st month, 3rd month, 4th month is the irregular visit(Filter these records).

I hope i clearly mentioned now the use-case.

Comment: these queries are not finale nor correct. For your input, the second query gives correct output. For a correct query it is needed analytic functions and more effort. What you should do is to understand them.

Comment: I am trying to lag function of analytic queries, but it is also not meeting my requirement. I want answer in HIve, but the above queries seems like sql. Ok let me try above second query in Oracle and make according to my requirement.